# When a user logs in, how can they view the website instead of the admin menu?

Tags: functions, login

I added Login/Logout buttons through a function:

```
// Add Login/Logout to Menu
    function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
        if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
            $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Log Out</a></li>';
        }
        elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
            $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
        }
        return $items;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );

    // Add Login/Logout to Menu
    function add_hamburger_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
        if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'hamburger') {
            $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Log Out</a></li>';
        }
        elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'hamburger') {
            $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
        }
        return $items;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_hamburger_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
```

*side question, if there's a way to merge this code I'd appreciate any pointers.

When a user logs in it takes them to the WordPress menu screen, I want it so when they login you're on the website and you have the admin toolbar.

Comment: If you do a search on the site you'll find a few articles which use [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)